# Script as an onload script

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onload, simulate

I got a script for a popunder but the popunder just opens if you click anywhere on the website. They did it like this to avoid that AdBlocks don't block the pounder. So now the question: Could anybody help me to write the script as an onload script. Simulating a click doesn't work.

Here the Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _pop = _pop || [];
    _pop.push(['siteId', 348021]);
    _pop.push(['minBid', 0]);
    _pop.push(['popundersPerIP', 0]);
    _pop.push(['delayBetween', 0]);
    _pop.push(['default', false]);
    _pop.push(['defaultPerDay', 0]);
    _pop.push(['topmostLayer', false]);
    (function() {
        var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        pa.src = '//c1.popads.net/pop.js';
        pa.onerror = function() {
            var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
            sa.src = '//c2.popads.net/pop.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
        };
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: This script already works onload.

Comment: Popunder is popup's nastier brother. I wouldn't visit a site displaying popups more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [Browsers are not allowed to show popups](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/browsers.html#allowed-to-show-a-pop-up) in response to load events (and are smart enough to tell the difference between a real click and a simulated one)